# Is it possible to score in Solr with multiple scoring functions?

Tags: solr, scoring, dismax

This is possible using dismax in Solr:

```
q=superman&qf=title^2 subject
```

Is it possible to score based on multiple query fields, e.g. by having multiple scoring functions? To grasp my idea I would like to do something like this:

```
q1=superman&q2=Oslo&q1f=title^2 subject&q2f=region district city^2
```

Comment: why you couldn't run it with 2 queries?

Comment: There would be other complications as this is just a part of more complicated query. I wanted to present minimal example of what I want to achieve. I am ok with either a solution or a proof that it is not possible.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's not possible by default